# I've got my private key compromised. How does CRL work?

Tags: public-key, certificates, pki, crl

How does certificate revocation list (CRL) work? How can I send a request to the CA to add my current private key to the CRL, so no one except me can add my certificate to the CRL?

<sub>Related:

- [How can we get CA's public key?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11712/6961)

- [I've got my private key compromised. How does CRL work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11713/6961)

- [What happens when a root CA has its private key compromised?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11714/6961)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the concrete CRL.

As long as you have access to your private key, you can sign the revocation request. This prevents anyone without access to the private key from issuing a faked revocation request.

With access to the private key, a faked revocation request can be sent. But in this case the damage is already done, and a revocation is actually helping the victim.

Comment: That makes sense. What protocol is used for CRL?

Comment: @evening Did you do **any** research before asking all your similar questions? Several places, including [Wikipedia's "Revocation list" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list) give you that information and/or link to related RFCs. You might also want to check on [Wikipedia's "Online Certificate Status Protocol" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) for more infos. Hope that helps…